# Can't get CMake's ExternalData to download

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to get cmake to download the external data I need for my test by following the advice at [this blog](https://crascit.com/2015/04/03/handling-binary-assets-and-test-data-with-cmake/)

But no matter what I try CMake keeps referring to a local file that doesn't exist.  My CMake code is:

```
include(ExternalData)
set(ExternalData_URL_TEMPLATES
   "http://testdata.local/SoftwareTestData/AutomatedTests/%(algo)/%(hash)"
)

ExternalData_Add_Test(it_GfFullData
   NAME it_GfFull
   COMMAND it_GfFull --input DATA{Flight3LCMLog-with_GF-2016-09-09_10-14-31.00} -t 10 -g 10190 -G 17000
)
ExternalData_Add_Target(it_GfFullData)

ExternalData_Expand_Arguments(it_GfFullData realpath  DATA{Flight3LCMLog-with_GF-2016-09-09_10-14-31.00})
message(STATUS "data = ${realpath}")
```

The md5 hash for my file is `9aa3da7f7fc62ecf9108febe51a785e9`, in the same directory as this `CMakeLists.txt` file I placed the file `Flight3LCMLog-with_GF-2016-09-09_10-14-31.00.md5`

At `http://testdata.local/SoftwareTestData/AutomatedTests/%(algo)/%(hash)` (where `algo=md5` and `hash=9aa3da7f7fc62ecf9108febe51a785e9`) I placed the binary file.

That message line I have keeps outputting the filename in my local build path.

When I check the access logs on the webserver, it doesn't even try to look for the file.

How can I get CMake to download my data?  I've been filling the system's `ExternalData.cmake` file with debug printouts, going through VTK to see how they do it, etc.. but no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the setup I have above is all but right.  The step that's missing is adding the data target as a dependency to the test.

Earlier I was testing this by building the test and running it with `ctest` - where it'd obviously fail.

By adding:

```
add_dependencies(it_GfFull it_GfFullData)
```

Now, when the test is built, it'll download the file.

When `ctest` calls my test, `DATA{Flight3LCMLog-with_GF-2016-09-09_10-14-31.00}` still expands to the original local path that was confusing me, but now that the file has downloaded, it's a symlink to the actual data file.

Without the `add_dependencies` step, I would have to otherwise make sure that the data target is built.  I was under the mistaken impression that the  `ExternalData_Add_Test` function somehow took care of ensuring the download target was called.